# How can I download web page automatically with onload?

Tags: javascript, html, file, download, onload

I am doing a very simple website, without images or anything, for my personal use where updated data is presented from several widgets and I want to be able to download that page in html, txt, xls or csv to my PC, every so often , no need for the browser to ask me for permission.
There are no security problems, because apart from the widgets, the page is on my PC.

Surfing I got these two codes but they don't do what I want:

```
Firt Code
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function download(text, name, type) { 
  var a = document.getElementById("a"); 
  var file = new Blob([text], {type: type}); 
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file); 
  a.download = name;                  
}
</script>

Second Code
<BODY>
<a href="" id="a">click here to download your file</a> 
<button onclick="download('file text', 'myfilename.txt', 'text/plain')">Create file</button>        

</BODY>

<body>
<button id="b">export to CSV</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function exportToCsv() {
        var myCsv = "Col1,Col2,Col3\nval1,val2,val3";

        window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(myCsv));
}

    var button = document.getElementById('b');
    button.addEventListener('click', exportToCsv);
</script>
</body>
```

The first code would do it, but it forces me to click on the button, and I want it done automatically without asking me for confirmation, much less file type, name or location. I want to start download page with onload.

The second code does something, but apart from that it forces me to click on the button, it writes to excel this: "Col1, Col2, Col3 \ nval1, val2, val3" and I want to download the page, obviously with the value that widgets have at the moment. By the way, it always save the .csv with a different name and I want always the same name.

Thank you very much everyone for your comments and patient explanations, I am starting with Javascript and I want to learn.

Comment: In first code just try triggering the click for the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

In order to automatically download the file, you can trigger the click event of the `a` you have.

This can be done like this:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#a").click();     
});
```

Plain JS

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("a").click();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to prove your solution, I believe that I have to integrate the first code with you solution, but ... Can you put the complete code I must write and if I have to download a plugin from https://jquery.com ?